# Toast message in AndEngine keeps returning a RuntimeException

Tags: android

I am creating an app which makes an API call to OpenStreetMaps to retrieve map data. I am creating a thread to download the map data but I want to display a Toast message to tell me that the file download has been complete.

I use Hassanpur's AndroidFileDownloader http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2011/04/android-development-downloading-a-file-from-the-web/ to download the file but every time I try to return a toast message my app crashes. Hassanpur provides a way to return toast messages and it works when I run his app but when I try to use it in my AndEngine code it crashes.

Here is my Main Activity:

```
public class ExampleLauncher extends ExpandableListActivity implements LocationListener {

private static final String PREF_LAST_APP_LAUNCH_VERSIONCODE_ID = "last.app.launch.versioncode";

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(!AndEngine.isDeviceSupported()) {
        this.showDialog(ExampleLauncher.DIALOG_DEVICE_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    }
    this.setContentView(R.layout.list_examples);
    this.mExpandableExampleLauncherListAdapter = new ExpandableExampleLauncherListAdapter(this);
    this.setListAdapter(this.mExpandableExampleLauncherListAdapter);

    // ===========================================================
    // My code - START
    // ===========================================================

    // variables for location detection
    LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // check if GPS is enabled
    if (!enabled) {
        // if not so to the location settings
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    } 

    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the location provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

    // location button
    this.findViewById(R.id.btn_get_location).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View pView) {

            // reset the API URL's in case the user has pressed the button twice
            resetAPIURLs();

            // get current location coordinates
            coordinates = new NortSouthEastWestBoundaries();

            // Display message
            Toast.makeText(ExampleLauncher.this, "Getting coordinates...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            getCoordinates();

            // check if a GPS location was determined
            if (latCurrentPos == 0){
                Toast.makeText(ExampleLauncher.this, "GPS detection failed\nMake sure you can receive a GPS signal\nPlease try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                generateBoundaryBoxCoordinates();

                // build up the two API URL's
                generateApiUrlUsingCoordinates(minLatSouth);
                generateApiUrlUsingCoordinates(minLonWest);
                generateApiUrlUsingCoordinates(maxLatNorth);
                buildApiUrlLastCoordinate(maxLonEast);

                nodeApiUrl += commonPartOfApiUrl;
                wayApiUrl += commonPartOfApiUrl;

                System.out.println(nodeApiUrl);
                System.out.println(wayApiUrl);
                // start 2 threads to make the API call and download the map data
                downloaderThread = null;
                progressDialog = null;

                downloaderThread = new DownloaderThread(thisActivity, nodeApiUrl, nodeFileName);
                downloaderThread.start();
                downloaderThread = new DownloaderThread(thisActivity, wayApiUrl, wayFileName);
                downloaderThread.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final SharedPreferences prefs = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    this.mVersionCodeCurrent = this.getVersionCode();
    this.mVersionCodeLastLaunch = prefs.getInt(ExampleLauncher.PREF_LAST_APP_LAUNCH_VERSIONCODE_ID, -1);

    if(this.isFirstTime("first.app.launch")) {
        this.showDialog(ExampleLauncher.DIALOG_FIRST_APP_LAUNCH);
    } else if((this.mVersionCodeLastLaunch != -1) && (this.mVersionCodeLastLaunch < this.mVersionCodeCurrent)){
        this.showDialog(ExampleLauncher.DIALOG_NEW_IN_THIS_VERSION);
    } else if(this.isFirstTime("please.submit.benchmarks")){
        this.showDialog(ExampleLauncher.DIALOG_BENCHMARKS_SUBMIT_PLEASE);
    }

    prefs.edit().putInt(ExampleLauncher.PREF_LAST_APP_LAUNCH_VERSIONCODE_ID, this.mVersionCodeCurrent).commit();
}
}
```

And here is the downloader class:

```
public class DownloaderThread extends Thread
{
// constants
private static final int DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;


// ===========================================================
// My code - START
// ===========================================================
// instance variables
private ExampleLauncher parentActivity;
private String downloadUrl;
private String fileName = "didntWork.xml";

private final String TAGDL = "[DL File]";

//  ToastHandler mToastHandler = new ToastHandler(parentActivity);
// ===========================================================
// My code - END
// ===========================================================
/**
 * Instantiates a new DownloaderThread object.
 * @param parentActivity Reference to AndroidFileDownloader activity.
 * @param inUrl String representing the URL of the file to be downloaded.
 */
public DownloaderThread(ExampleLauncher inParentActivity, String inUrl, String fileName)
{
    this.fileName = fileName;
    downloadUrl = "";
    if(inUrl != null)
    {
        downloadUrl = inUrl;
    }
    parentActivity = inParentActivity;
}

/**
 * Connects to the URL of the file, begins the download, and notifies the
 * AndroidFileDownloader activity of changes in state. Writes the file to
 * the root of the SD card.
 */
@Override
public void run()
{
    URL url;
    URLConnection conn;
    int fileSize, lastSlash;
    BufferedInputStream inStream;
    BufferedOutputStream outStream;
    File outFile;
    FileOutputStream fileStream;
    Message msg;

    // we're going to connect now
    //msg = Message.obtain(parentActivity.activityHandler,
    //      ExampleLauncher.MESSAGE_CONNECTING_STARTED,
    //      0, 0, downloadUrl);
    //parentActivity.activityHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    Toast.makeText(parentActivity, fileName + " download started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try
    {

        Log.d(TAGDL, "File DL Started");
        url = new URL(downloadUrl);
        conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        fileSize = conn.getContentLength();

        /**
        // get the filename
        lastSlash = url.toString().lastIndexOf('/');
        fileName = "file.bin";
        if(lastSlash >=0)
        {
            fileName = url.toString().substring(lastSlash + 1);
        }
        if(fileName.equals(""))
        {
            fileName = "file.bin";
        }*/

        // notify download start
        int fileSizeInKB = fileSize / 1024;
        //msg = Message.obtain(parentActivity.activityHandler,
        //      ExampleLauncher.MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_STARTED,
        //      fileSizeInKB, 0, fileName);
        //parentActivity.activityHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // start download
        inStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        // ===========================================================
        // My code
        // ===========================================================

        outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName);

        Log.d(TAGDL, "String Path -> " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName);

        // ===========================================================
        // My code
        // ===========================================================

        fileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileStream, DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE);
        byte[] data = new byte[DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = 0, totalRead = 0;
        while(!isInterrupted() && (bytesRead = inStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) >= 0)
        {
            outStream.write(data, 0, bytesRead);

            // update progress bar
            totalRead += bytesRead;
            int totalReadInKB = totalRead / 1024;
            //msg = Message.obtain(parentActivity.activityHandler,
            //      ExampleLauncher.MESSAGE_UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR,
            //      totalReadInKB, 0);
            //parentActivity.activityHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }

        outStream.close();
        fileStream.close();
        inStream.close();

        if(isInterrupted())
        {
            // the download was canceled, so let's delete the partially downloaded file
            outFile.delete();
            Toast.makeText(parentActivity, fileName + " download interrupted...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAGDL, "File DL Failed");
            //mToastHandler.showToast(fileName + " download interrupted...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        else
        {
            // notify completion
            //msg = Message.obtain(parentActivity.activityHandler,
            //      ExampleLauncher.MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
            //parentActivity.activityHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            //Toast.makeText(parentActivity, fileName + " download successful...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAGDL, "File DL Successful");
            //mToastHandler.showToast(fileName + " downloaded successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

    }
    catch(MalformedURLException e)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(parentActivity, fileName + " download failed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAGDL, "File DL Failed");
        //mToastHandler.showToast(fileName + " download failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        //String errMsg = parentActivity.getString(R.string.error_message_bad_url);
        //msg = Message.obtain(parentActivity.activityHandler,
        //      ExampleLauncher.MESSAGE_ENCOUNTERED_ERROR,
        //      0, 0, errMsg);
        //parentActivity.activityHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
```

Has anyone got any idea why I get this error?

```
04-27 23:23:53.496: W/dalvikvm(20509): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught       exception (group=0x415b1d40)
04-27 23:23:53.496: E/AndroidRuntime(20509): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1469
04-27 23:23:53.496: E/AndroidRuntime(20509): Process: org.andengine.examples, PID: 20509
04-27 23:23:53.496: E/AndroidRuntime(20509): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-27 23:23:53.496: E/AndroidRuntime(20509):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
04-27 23:23:53.496: E/AndroidRuntime(20509):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
04-27 23:23:53.496: E/AndroidRuntime(20509):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:327)
04-27 23:23:53.496: E/AndroidRuntime(20509):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
04-27 23:23:53.496: E/AndroidRuntime(20509):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
04-27 23:23:53.496: E/AndroidRuntime(20509):    at com.locationracing.app.DownloaderThread.run(DownloaderThread.java:109)
04-27 23:23:53.506: W/dalvikvm(20509): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415b1d40)
```

If anyone else is having trouble with something like this then read the comments below the top answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to create a toast inside another other thread. Toast should can be only create on the ui/main thread...

**solution:**

Create your toast inside the runOnUIThread to call the main thread.

**change:**

```
Toast.makeText(parentActivity, fileName + " download started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**to:**

```
parentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(parentActivity, fileName + " download started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I tried that and I got this error `04-28 00:47:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(26033): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1679
04-28 00:47:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(26033): Process: org.andengine.examples, PID: 26033
04-28 00:47:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(26033): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 00:47:15.956: E/AndroidRuntime(26033):  at com.locationracing.app.DownloaderThread.run(DownloaderThread.java:110)
`

Comment: new DownloaderThread(this, nodeApiUrl, nodeFileName); it souhld be this not thisactivity

Comment: Sorry @Rod_Algonquin When I change it to `new DownloaderThread(this, nodeApiUrl, nodeFileName);` it changes `public DownloaderThread(ExampleLauncher inParentActivity, String inUrl, String fileName)` to `public DownloaderThread(OnClickListener onClickListener, String inUrl, String fileName)` and causes another error

Comment: @woppers it should be new DownloaderThread(ExampleLauncher.this, nodeApiUrl, nodeFileName); to reference to the main class

Comment: you are a legend! Thanks a million for that. That is after wrecking my buzz for ages!